# SQL Query fails in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, sql, sqldatasource

I need to display data on a chart from a database. As far as I can tell, the chart has to be bound to a DataSource which in my case is a SqlDataSource. My query to get this data is:

```
SELECT A.a, A.b, B.b, C.b 
FROM (SELECT * FROM T WHERE T.c = 'str1') A, 
     (SELECT * FROM T WHERE T.c = 'str2') B, 
     (SELECT * FROM T WHERE T.c = 'str3') C 
WHERE A.a = B.a AND A.a = C.a AND A.d = B.d AND A.d = C.d
```

This works fine in Oracle SQL Developer, but when configuring the SqlDataSource in Visual Studio, I can execute the query in the Query Builder, but it displays an error on the next page--the Test Query page. The error I get is:

> There was an error executing the query. Please check the syntax of the command and if present, the types and values of the parameters and ensure they are correct.
>
> Syntax Error: Expecting identifier or quoted identifier.

What's causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is the datasource still Oracle?  Or does the data reside in SQL Server now?  If still Oracle, check out this link - http://forums.asp.net/t/971053.aspx?Syntax+Error+Expecting+identifier+or+quoted+identifier

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)